# Слова в текстовом файле с новой строки

Tags: c++, fstream

У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором слова  представлены следующим образом:[image: слова в 1 файле]
Есть код, который выбирает слово из случайной строки и передает его в переменную **wordtogame**.

```
    read.open("WORDSLIST.txt");
if (!(read.is_open)())
    cout << "Файл со словами не открыт\n";
while (getline(read, str))
    stringnumber++;
wordtotake = rand() % (stringnumber)+1;  

read.close();
read.open("WORDSLIST.txt"); 

while (getline(read, str))
{
    if (wordtotake == 1)
    {
        int lenthstr = str.length();
        wordtogame = str.substr(0, lenthstr - 0);
        break;
    }
    --wordtotake;
}
read.close();
```

Для того, что бы этот код работал, нужно, что бы все слова в файле были записаны с новой строки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это сделать? То есть, слова в файле должны выглядеть так:[image: слова в 2 файле]
Возможно ли вообще такое сделать в рамках использования fstream?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну я же уже вам отвечал! После вывода слова выводите `'\n'`!

Comment: понимаете ли, тут это не сработает. У меня изначально дан файл из которого случайно выбираются слова. Я не вывожу все эти слова.  То есть, я не могу просто вывести их через '\n', нужно что бы они в этом же файле разделились на строки, и уже отредактированный вариант я бы использовал. Просто вручную сидеть и переносить слова на новую строку долго)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, вам надо простая программа:

```
int main() {
    string s;
    while(cin >> s) cout << s << "\n";
    }
```

Далее запустить ее (пусть она для определенности называется convert.exe) из командной строки

```
convert.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

И все. Все слова из файла `input.txt` будут записаны в файл `output.txt` в новый строках. Подставьте свои конкретные иимена, и дальше переименовывайте эти файлы как хотите.